# How to add/use aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker in node_modules

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, datepicker, aurelia

I'm new to aurelia and wanted to add a datepicker in my form, I saw this [post](https://www.danyow.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-aurelia/) from danyow, showing how to add datepicker using jquery. But would love to use a datepicker from bootstrap.

And so I saw this [another post](http://www.roore.se/news/bootstrap-datepicker/index.html), haven't tried the second link because as I'm scanning the node_modules (if it matters, I use the spa templates found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)), I saw a folder **aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker** and under the **src** folder, there's a **aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker.js** in which the content is pretty much the same with the second link.

Can I use that folder to have a datepicker? If yes, how? Or should I just follow the second link to create one myself?

What I tried:

- use it as feature in my `boot.ts` file `aurelia.use.standardConfiguration().feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker'));`
- use it as a plugin
- require it on my html file

Everything above, nothing is working for me.

Please advise. Thanks

**EDIT:**

**boot.ts**

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap';
declare const IS_DEV_BUILD: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
        .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-validation'));

    if (IS_DEV_BUILD) {
        aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
    }

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app/components/app/app')));
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { AureliaPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'app': 'aurelia-bootstrapper' },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: ['ClientApp', 'node_modules'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/i, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'ts-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/i, use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild) }),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            }),
            new AureliaPlugin({ aureliaApp: 'boot' })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]')  // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    }];
}
```

[image: screenshot_node_modules]

Comment: What does it say in the readme?

Comment: I followed the readme. I got stuck on step 3. Step 1 and 2 is installing and to make sure I use manual aurelia bootstrapping. But on step 3, it says I needed to include it as a plugin, like so `.plugin('aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker')` but it says it can't find the module.

Comment: Well that's the error right there. Your loader or packager is not picking it up. It's difficult to say without seeing how that's configured.  if it says to add it as a plug-in then you should add it as a plugin then that's what you need to do but you haven't configured your tools correctly

Comment: what files do you want me to put in the question? please tell me so I can show it to you, been searching for answers 2 days

Comment: Your main file and your loader or bundler config file would be helpful.

Comment: please see my updated question. i believe that is the main file and bundler your asking for but if you would like to see more files. please do let me know.

Comment: It's worth noting that when something isn't working correctly you should simplify your setup. For example, you are obviously not the point where you need to use `UglifyJsPlugin`. Anyway you need to add the line from the readme back to your boot.ts file

Comment: Yes. I have no other plugin except the `aurelia-validation`. This is just a scaffolded project that was generated from the templates and I'm trying to add a datepicker. I've added the line but still having same error. By any chance, did you spot the error?

Comment: No, but you can try referencing it using the full path like like you used for the bootstrap CSS file. Also scaffolders are evil.

Comment: Also can you describe where the error is thrown? Does webpack throw it when you try to bundle? does it come from the typescript loader? Is it raised by the framework's runtime element loader?

Comment: Here is the message shown in the console, `Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker/aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker` and if I include it as a feature is says `Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker/index`

Comment: First of all you have to include it is a plug-in because that's what the documentation says. Anyway from that error message and from the screenshot of the directory, it is clear that there is no such file. Try `aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker/src')`

Comment: Got it. Have also tried that before with `/src` but to no avail :(

Comment: Try adding `index.js`. Aurelia uses module paths like these to specify everything which is actually really nice and consistent. To load something, you just have to make sure that it can resolve the file relative to where your app is

Comment: Still brother, same error :(

Comment: Try specifying the full relative path to the file like `'../node_modules/aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker/src/index.js'`. That's obviously not something you want to do in a long-term but it will always give you an idea where the issue is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152393/discussion-between-boy-pasmo-and-aluan-haddad).